# how to protect color from theme influence

Tags: xamarin.forms

in my application the background color is calculated according to the color of the picture, and if everything is fine on a light theme, then the color is distorted on a dark theme, tell me please how can I fix this?

Xaml:

```
<StackLayout Margin="0" Padding="0" Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="{Binding HeaderColor}" HeightRequest="135" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
```

[Light theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkBpe.png)

[DarkTheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQwwr.png)

Comment: Can you show the code for  "calculated according to the color of the picture"

Comment: What does the `the color is distorted ` mean? Your want to the background color is same on the light and dark theme?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT, I mean that the color calculated in the code should be displayed unchanged on both dark and light theme.

Comment: Oh, I see, in the dark theme, the color of the picture is different from the background. But the picture's color is fixed, and background color is calculated according to the color of the picture. So the background color is fixed too.

Comment: @BasH, the code doesn't actually do anything special, it just loops through the image pixels and outputs the color that dominates the image (not to be confused with the middle color), pixels with transparency are ignored. But I also tried to hardcode the yellow color assignment and it gets distorted just the same.